Is a product of two compact spaces compact, even without the axiom of choice?
Let $X, Y$ be compact topological spaces (every open cover has a finite subcover).  The usual proof that $X \times Y$ is compact goes as follows: Let $M$ be an open cover of $X\times Y$, and for each $x\in X$ use the compactness of $Y$ to show that that there exists some finite subset $M_x \subset M$ which covers $\{x\} \times Y$.  Now, $M_x$ actually covers $U_x \times Y$ for some open neighborhood $U_x \ni x$.  (This is the meat of the proof IMO.)  Finally, using the compactness of $X$ we know that a finite number of $U_x$ cover $X$, and thus $X \times Y$ is covered by a finite union of the finite unions $M_x$.
However, this proof evidently uses the Axiom of Choice at the point where we select $M_x$ for each $x \in X$.  I usually try to be mindful of when AC is actually needed for a proof versus when it's just used for convenience, so is there another way to do this which does not require AC?
